# How to set up a/b testing in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, testing

Is there anyone in this forum that can explain how a/b (split) testing can be set up in Magento 1.9+?

I have searched on the internet but couldn't find real help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento doesn't have an out of the box solution for this. You have to create a custom module. Few solutions (free modules) exists for magento regarding a/b testing.

This one here works: https://github.com/Creare/Magento_ABTesting

It has a few problems if you use varnish cache, but it is the only free module out there that works: it serves to 50% of your customers your theme A and to the other half theme B. Then it monitors everything using 3 GA accounts: one master, one for theme A and one for theme B.

Detailed info:
https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/ab-split-testing-magento-with-google-analytics-cro

Comment: gonna try that one... strange that there aren't more options available